# Extended RGB colors using SetConsoleTextAttribute

Tags: c, winapi, colors, console

According to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences), using the string `"\x1b[38;2;105;105;105m"` can be used to change the text colors in the win32 color. It works fine, and this behavior works only on certain versions of Windows 10+.

Since this is using extended colors that take an RGB code rather than the predefined `COLOR_XXX` codes, I can't figure out how to implement this using `SetConsoleTextAttribute`. I need the same closest-matching color to be set, because this console app will also be used on pre-windows 10 systems.

For example, instead of using `FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_RED | WHATEVER_COLOR` is there a way to pass in the same RGB color codes?

Comment: *this console app will also be used on pre-windows 10 systems.* So the question is about Windows 7 or earlier dysfunctional versions? Forget about the transient 8 and 9. Bear in mind that a console is a very crude output device. Consider using a proper GUI.

Comment: @WeatherVane you cannot be serious right now

Comment: It wasn't a joke. Consoles are crude output devices. Who really cares whether the colour is gauche or mauve?

Comment: If consoles are so bad why are so many things console-based? So many GUI programs have their console counterparts; colors are not a wild request for characters printed on the screen. Also, I cannot understand why you think Windows 7 and earlier systems are dysfunctional -- if they are nobody would use them!

Comment: Yes but console output generally lacks finesse, and is no better from attempts to improve it. And I didn't say that Windows 7 is dysfunctional. I said that some of the earlier versions were. Basically everything between (but excluding) XP and Win7.

Comment: Okay, fair, I was wrong. But that's still your opinion. But I still want to run my (console) programs (with text colors) on them (earlier dysfunctional versions). I'll wait for an actual answer in the meantime while trying to figure this out.

Comment: Ever tried automating a CLI application? That's an all-around horrible experience, with a brittle solution at best. And once your initial solution appears to work, you try it with a pseudo console in between, and realize that it's time to start over. There are very, very few reasons to want to write a CLI, and when you need color, you're probably just avoiding the actual solution: A GUI application.

Comment: I am just asking how to make a line of text a specific color -- either I can or I can't. I have no idea why the fact that my program is console based has anything to do with my question. It also makes no sense to rebuild it from the ground up for such a basic thing when I already have put so much into it.